# Average speed question of a car on an oval track

Tags: average

On an oval track, a car averages $30$ M.P.H. (miles per hour) for the first lap (a lap is $1$ mile around the track).  At what average speed must that same car drive the 2nd lap on that same track so that the average speed of both laps is $60$ M.P.H.?

Comment: This is a classical wrong solution

Comment: @JohnD: This properly belongs on physics.SE. Average speeds don't add up like that.

Comment: A wrong solution is funny but a "classical" wrong solution is even funnier.

Comment: The time available to complete the second lap is zero. 60 MPH is the limit average speed for both laps as the average speed for the second approaches $\infty$.

Comment: This seems like a good problem to give high school math students.  I think the average person would get it wrong.  I suspect the most likely answer would be $90$.

Answer (score 3):

Average speed = Distance / Time = harmonic mean of two speeds

60 = (2*30*x)/(30+x);
30+x=x;
0=30

This is not true, so there is no solution.

I'm not sure if this is correct, so if you want to check my work...

Comment: I'll give Pakquebchsoflwty the checkmark cuz it appears he/she needs it more than Mario G but Mario G's answer and post are actually better.  Anybody object to that?

Answer (score 3):

First lap lasts $1/30$ hour, let $v_2$ M.P.H. the speed for the second lap, a time $t_2=\frac{1}{v_2}$ hours is required, then the average speed of the two laps is $$\overline{v}=\frac{\overbrace{1}^\text{Distance covered in the first lap}+\overbrace{1}^\text{Distance covered in the second lap}}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{30}}_\text{Time needed for the first lap}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{v_2}}_\text{Time needed for the second lap}}=\frac{60v_2}{v_2+30}$$
And $\overline{v}=60$ M.P.H. iff 
\begin{align*}
&&\frac{60v_2}{v_2+30}&=60\\
\iff &&60v_2&=60v_2+1800\\
\iff &&0&=1800
\end{align*}
Therefore, it's not possible to attain an average speed of $60$ M.P.H.

Comment: Nice work "buddy".  I fixed (edited) your slight typos/misspellings.

Answer (score 0):

A friend asked me this question (as a brain teaser I suppose), and I got it right the first time (although my thinking came across some wrong solutions first which I quickly fixed before emailing him my correct answer).  Think of it like this.  Imagine $2$ cars on this oval track, call them cars A and B.  A drives the first lap (mile) at $30$ MPH average speed, therefore taking $2$ minutes to drive the first $1$ mile.  Since the question is asking for an average speed of $60$ MPH over $2$ laps ($2$ miles), we know that it takes $2$ minutes to drive $2$ miles at $60$ MPH.  Therefore there is no speed (not even the speed of light) for the 2nd lap of car A that will give it an average speed of $60$ MPH for the $2$ miles because after $2$ minutes, car A is only at the $1$ mile marker and has $1$ more mile to go!

It may help if you imagine car B going a constant $60$ MPH, after $2$ minutes car B would be done the "race" but car A would only be halfway, so even if it had nitrous, a supercharger, dual turbochargers...  there is no way it will ever get the $60$ MPH average speed for the $2$ miles with that slow start.

Moral of the story... don't be a "pussyfooter" when it comes to racing cars.

Now had I changed the problem to $40$ MPH for the first lap, then there WOULD be a solution.

Comment: $2$ comments:  $1$: It is amazing how many "regular" (not math oriented) people get this wrong, giving answers like $60$ or $90$.  $2$: There is a "solution" if we "misinterpret" average to mean strictly the average of the $2$ average speeds, disregarding the duration at those speeds.  For example, $2$ minutes at 30 MPH and $40$ seconds at $90$ MPH will cover $2$ miles in $2$ min $40$ seconds which is less than $60$ MPH average speed by the normal definition, but if we don't care about time taken, then ($30$+$90$)/$2$ does indeed equal $60$.